# What is a closure #1 error in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I am having trouble debugging this error. I use Crashlytics on my iOS app and have been seeing this error in a few of my apps. Here is part of the stack trace:

[image]

Here is my code inside of BusStopTimesViewController.swift (I comment what is line 140 since that seems to be where the problem is happening according to the trace):

```
func loadBusData(_ busUrl: String) {
    let urlString = busUrl
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!

    ...

    if passingTimePredicted != "" {
        let nextBusDate = dateFormatter.date(from: passingTimePredicted)

        // THE FOLLOWING LINE IS LINE 140
        var minutesUntilBus = (nextBusDate!.timeIntervalSince1970 - Date().timeIntervalSince1970) / 60

        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: nextBusDate!)
        let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: nextBusDate!)

        ...
    }
}
```

My initial thought is it is because nextBusDate is nil and I am trying to work with it, but I don't think that is it because the error says nothing about nextBusDate being nil (although I should probably check if it is nil before working with it). I am confused on what this error about (closure #1) is? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `dateFormatter.date(from: passingTimePredicted)`  will return optional value  will crash if it is nil  because of `nextBusDate!.timeIntervalSince1970` **Never forcefully unwrap the optional types !!**

Comment: This is what I thought was causing the error message, but why is it mentioning something about a closure? Usually when the crash happens because of trying to forcefully unwrap optional type that is nil it will indicate that in the error message :S I am a bit confused what the part about the closure means, it makes me think that something else is causing the error?

Comment: Not sure !! but  Looks like you are calling this method from closure body  like from API response closure

Comment: Once you fix the code to avoid the `!`, you can get the difference in minutes more simply with `var minutesUntilBus = nextBusDate.timeIntervalSinceNow / 60`

Comment: remove all the ! (force unwrapping) and then try.

Comment: Having same question. In a crash log `closure #1 in Type.method(arg:) + 142`, does that mean first closure inside this method Or this method is called some where else by a closure?

Comment: Never mind, by referring line +142, it means first closure inside that method. Late thought :)